# How do printf and scanf handle floating point precision formats?

Tags: c, floating-point, double, precision

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
float val1 = 214.20;
double val2 = 214.20;

printf("float : %f, %4.6f, %4.2f \n", val1, val1, val1);
printf("double: %f, %4.6f, %4.2f \n", val2, val2, val2);
```

Which outputs:

```
float : 214.199997,  214.199997, 214.20 | <- the correct value I wanted 
double: 214.200000,  214.200000, 214.20 |
```

I understand that `214.20` has an infinite binary representation. The first two elements of the first line have an approximation of the intended value, but the the last one seems to have no approximation at all, and this led me to the following question:

**How do the `scanf`, `fscanf`, `printf`, `fprintf` (etc.) functions treat the precision formats?**

With no precision provided, `printf` printed out an approximated value, but with `%4.2f` it gave the correct result. Can you explain me the algorithm used by these functions to handle precision?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The thing is, 214.20 cannot be expressed *exactly* with binary representation. Few decimal numbers can. So an approximation is stored. Now when you use printf, the binary representation is turned into a decimal representation, but it again cannot be expressed exactly and is only approximated.

As you noticed, you can give a precision to printf to tell it how to round the decimal approximation. And if you don't give it a precision then a precision of 6 is assumed (see the man page for details).

If you use `%.40f` for the float and `%.40lf` for the double in your example above, you will get these results:

```
214.1999969482421875000000000000000000000000
214.1999999999999886313162278383970260620117
```

They are different because with double, there are more bits to better approximate 214.20. But as you can see, they are still very odd when represented in decimal.

I recommend to read the [Wikipedia article on floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) for more insights about how floating point numbers work. An excellent read is also [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Thanks for answering, though my question still is at same place. In the first place itself the float could NOT contain the exact value of 214.20, then how could it regain it ONLY with %4.2f precision, and NOT with %4.6f. What did it do to regain the value. I understand that approximation is done, but WHAT WAS THE BIT PATTERN USED THAT CAUSED INTERNALLY STORED 214.199997 TO BECOME 214.20 AND HOW DID WE ARRIVED AT THAT?

Comment: Not sure I get you, but that's just the [rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding). It's pure chance that `%4.2f` gives you exactly the value that you wanted. It's still "wrong" since the binary representation is *not* equivalent to 214.20 but to 214.1999969482421875. Now, if you round "214.1999969482421875" to 6 digits, you get "214.199997" because the 7th digit is a 9, turning the 6 into a 7. But when you only round to 2 digits, you get "214.20" because the 3rd digit is a nine, so you need to increase the 9 on the 2nd digit. That "overflows" to 10, turning the ".19" into ".20".

Comment: Oh!! I believe you are trying to say that this operation is done in decimal representation, and that's how 214.199997 was formed as a round effect of double precision. Because had it been in binary representation we already confirmed that 214.20 is NOT representable in binary, with all rounding skills used.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to say :-)

Answer (score 4):

Since you asked about `scanf`, one thing you should note is that POSIX requires `printf` and a subsequent `scanf` (or `strtod`) to reconstruct the original value **exactly** as long as sufficiently significant digits (at least `DECIMAL_DIG`, I believe) were printed. Plain C of course makes no such requirement; the C standard pretty much allows floating point operations to give whatever result the implementor likes as long as they document it. However, if your intent is to store floating point numbers in text files to be read back later, you might be better off using the C99 `%a` specifier to print them in hex. This way they'll be exact and there's no confusion about whether the serialize/deserialize process loses precision.

Keep in mind thatr when I said "reconstruct the original value", I mean the actual value which was held in the variable/expression passed to `printf`, not the original decimal you wrote in the source file which got rounded to the best binary representation by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` will round the input value to the nearest exactly representable floating point value.  As DarkDust's answer illustrates, in single precision the closest exactly representable value is below the exact value, and in double precision the closest exactly representable value is above the exact value.

Comment: If it was possible to do so, why did we store approximation in first place ? :-). Excuse me if I am causing pain, but that what I wanted to know, what does scanf does to represent a value that was given in six places after decimal to get converted into two points after decimal. Given that .20 is NOT representable in binary floating point

Comment: It looks like this follow-up question is answered in the comment dialog with DarkDust.