# in c, asking to scanf 1 digit after point and getting gybrish

Tags: c

i am wishing to scan a float with 1 digit accuration after FP.

this is the test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    float f;

    scanf("%.1f",&f);
    printf("%f",f);
}
```

i have entered 1.234, expecting to see 1.2 but instead
i was seeing this weird result :
 -107374176.000000

running VS2010, any ideas how to fix please?

Comment: `void main` is neither legal C nor legal C++. You should get better learning material.

Comment: scanf and printf don't use the same mini-language for format specifiers, and scanf can't do what you are asking.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789997/how-do-printf-and-scanf-handle-floating-point-precision-formats

Comment: Floating point variables in C know nothing about "digit accuracy". Always work to the best accuracy available, and reduce that for output. It is bad enough that floating point variables cannot store an exact representation of every real number.

Comment: @BaummitAugen C specifies certain function signatures for `main()`, `void main()` is not a specified one yet others are allowed per "...  in some other implementation-deﬁned manner."  C11 5.1.2.2.1  1  So for OP [VS2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh(v=vs.100).aspx) **is legal** and confirms to C with  implementation-deﬁned code.  You should get better learning material

Comment: "wishing to scan a float with 1 digit accuration (precision) after FP" --> OK, what should code do with characters the follow like `"34"`?  Declare an error, quietly ignore them, leave them for the next input function?  There is an answer for your coding coding, but it is presently too vague.

Comment: @chux Fair enough, I deserved that one. Still, if their learning material needlessly teaches implementation specific stuff like that to beginners, I suggest to use something else.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I [2nd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_(parliamentary_procedure)) your [_suggestion_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42879595/in-c-asking-to-scanf-1-digit-after-point-and-getting-gybrish?noredirect=1#comment72864704_42879595).

Answer (score 1):

It prints random numbers because the call to `scanf` failed and you are printing an uninitialized variable.

The floating point precision specification only applies in calls to `printf`, not to `scanf`. The format specifier you gave is simply invalid.

You would have known the call failed, had you checked the return value of `scanf`, which is equal to the number of format specifiers that were successfully converted.

If you want a specific accuracy for the number, you'd need to read it in full and then preform the truncation/rounding operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, you can make scanf() read a specific number of characters if you want like

```
float value;
scanf("%4f", &value);
```

and suppose the input is

**`43.23`**

it will read

```
43.2
```

but you can't specify precision.

what you can do is

```
float value;
if (scanf("%f", &value) == 1)
    printf("%.2f\n", value);
```

after all, the precision is limited by the binary representation, so making it have only two decimal places is pointless since in arithmetic operations it might be rounded.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%.1f",&f);
```

Your format specifier in the `scanf()` function is incorrect; you cannot specify the number of decimal places you want in as input for `scanf()`,  you can only do that when you want to output the floating point number using `printf()`.

You need to accept the input in full with `scanf()`:

```
scanf("%f",&f);
```

And then print out the number you want to the desired number of decimal places:

```
printf("%.1f", f);
```

This will print out `1.234` as `1.2`.

---

**Also**, `main()` needs to have a return type of `int` by default; `void main()` is not legal in C or C++. Even if you do not want to return anything from `main()`, define it as:

```
int main(void)
```