# How could I write a loop that prompts the user to enter a temperature value and stores that value in the array?

Tags: arrays, c

```
> #include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   double temp[7];
   int i;

   for (i = 0; i <=7; i++) {
      printf("Enter the day %d temp:\n",i);
      scanf(" %.1lf\n",&temp[i]);
   }

   

   return 0;
}
```

How could I write a loop that prompts the user to enter a temperature value and store that value in the array?

Comment: Does your code work? If no, how?

Comment: It doesn't, it asks me to input the first element and then quite

Comment: The compiler should have given you warnings. Did you see any? Also, always check the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: No i didn't see any

Comment: Well, first, I think you mean `i < 7`, not `i <= 7`.

Comment: What does stepping through the code in the debugger show you?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? This is the warning from gcc: *warning: unknown conversion type character ‘.’ in format [-Wformat=] scanf(" %.1lf\n",&temp[i]);*. The dot is not a valid flag for `scanf`. You may be confusing it with the `printf` precision specifier but that is not valid for `scanf`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42879595/in-c-asking-to-scanf-1-digit-after-point-and-getting-gybrish - look at the third answer

Comment: @kaylum you Nailed it !!!!!!!
Thank you so much

Comment: Remove `\n` from the format string